# Yarn install with private github repo failing

Tags: javascript, git, github, yarnpkg

I'm on a Windows 11 machine using a private github repo in my package.json.  I'm using yarn 1.22.19.  When doing `yarn install`, I get the following error:

```
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git
Directory: C:\path\to\dir
Output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I do an `npm i`, everything succeeds without an issue.  I've tried deleting `yarn.lock` and regenerating it, but I'm met with the same error.  I think the interesting thing is if I run the command `git ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git` individually, it works fine.  It's almost like yarn is ignoring my ssh tokens or something, but I don't know how to test that theory.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by updating to the latest Yarn version (3.5).